# "specified cast is invalid" C#

Tags: winforms, exception

When I try to open a form that doesnt get any parameter ,"specified cast is invalid" exception is thrown. The form loads succesfully but when I call form.showdialog it's throwing the exception. I don't know ,what can I do? I can show the form only when I call it from the program.cs
Thank you

Comment: Difficult to answer without code to look at

Comment: its compkicated to publish my code because its in computer that doesnt has access to internet or usb devise. can you give me some notes to check? I didnt mention that the form create in another form that run in separate thread

Comment: Well, if the error raises when you call ShowDialog() I suppose that you have something that fails in the Form_Load or Form_Shown event

Comment: "I didnt mention that the form create in another form that run in separate thread"  Why are you creating forms in another thread?

Comment: because I want to load it without stack the UI.

Comment: I did some tries and the conclusion is. when I call showdialog in the main thread no exception has been throwing, but if I called showdialog from. a form in another thread it threw the exception.. any idea?